# How to solve this problem {"first_name":["This field is required."],"last_name":["This field is required."]}?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, crud

I am trying to make multi-step form in react with axios POST request. Problem is when I am    clicking "next" button on second page there problem like {"first_name":["This field is required."],"last_name":["This field is required."]}. How I can solve this problem?

I tried write require in my input tags thought it will help but it doesn't.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const url = "http://34.89.133.245/api/auth/register/";

export function Registr() {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    password_confirm: "",
  });
  const [currentStep, setCurrentStep] = useState(1);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setFormData((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // do nothing here, we'll handle the form submission in useEffect
  };

  const goToNextStep = () => {
    setCurrentStep((prevState) => prevState + 1);
  };

  const goToPreviousStep = () => {
    setCurrentStep((prevState) => prevState - 1);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const submitData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.post(url, formData);
        console.log(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };

    if (currentStep === 3) {
      submitData();
    }
  }, [currentStep, formData]);

  const renderStep1 = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>
          First Name:
          <input
            required
            type="text"
            name="firstName"
            value={formData.firstName}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </label>
        <br />
        <label>
          Last Name:
          <input
            required
            type="text"
            name="lastName"
            value={formData.lastName}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </label>
        <br />
        <button onClick={goToNextStep}>Next</button>
      </div>
    );
  };

  const renderStep2 = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>
          Email:
          <input
            type="email"
            name="email"
            value={formData.email}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </label>
        <br />
        <label>
          Password:
          <input
            type="password"
            name="password"
            value={formData.password}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <label>
          Password Confirm:
          <input
            type="password"
            name="password_confirm"
            value={formData.password_confirm}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </label>
        <br />
        <button onClick={goToPreviousStep}>Previous</button>
        <button onClick={goToNextStep}>OK</button>
      </div>
    );
  };

  const renderStep3 = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Thank you for registering!</p>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      {currentStep === 1 && renderStep1()}
      {currentStep === 2 && renderStep2()}
      {currentStep === 3 && renderStep3()}
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: Have you tried renaming `firstName` to `first_name` and `lastName` to `last_name` in input label name?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have in your component `renderStep1` two inputs as required (with the name *fristName* and *lastName*)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).